# How to set it hor and vertically in the middle of page with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Excuse me for my English]
I just centered my "logo" horizontally and vertically.
But what I want is that when I resize my browser that my logo becomes a little bit smaller. How can I do this in bootstrap?

Index.html

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bg">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

screen.css

```
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("../images/comingsoon.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use viewport units <sup>(1)</sup> `vw` and `vh` with the `background-size` to make the size of the background depends on the window width and height

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/y9m44wa4/)

```css
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("//placehold.it/400x200/00AA00/ffffff?text=Coming Soon") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:50vw 40vh; /*added this */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:orange;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container"><div class="bg"></div></div>
</section>
```

---

Or you can use percentage values, change change the above `background-size` line into this:

```
background-size:50% 40%;
```

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/y9m44wa4/1/)

From [MDN - Background-Size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values):

> A **`<percentage>`** value that scales the background image in the corresponding dimension to the specified percentage of the background positioning area, which is determined by the value of background-origin. The background positioning area is, by default, the area containing the content of the box and its padding; the area may also be changed to just the content or to the area containing borders, padding, and content. ***`If the background's attachment is fixed, the background positioning area is instead the entire area of the browser window, not including the area covered by scrollbars if they are present`***. Negative percentages are not allowed.

---

***Note*** that the `50vw`, `40vh`, `50%` and `40%` are just values for demonstration purposes, you can put any positive values you want.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(1)</sup> Resources:

- [CanIuse - Viewport Units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
- [MDN - Viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size`:

```
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("../images/comingsoon.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

This will make your background image resizable, because it's relative to the parent size.

More information:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp